# Laravel 5.8 controller Index function returning blank page

Tags: laravel, view, controller, routes

I have created a new resource controller but my index function returns a blank page without any error.

**Here is my route:**

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'admin'], function (){

        Route::resource('admin/users', 'AdminUsersController');
        Route::resource('admin/posts', 'AdminPostsController');
        Route::resource('admin/comments', 'PostCommentsController');
        Route::resource('admin/categories', 'AdminCategoriesController');
        Route::resource('admin/comment/replies', 'CommentsRepliesController');
        Route::resource('admin/products', 'AdminProductsController');
        Route::resource('admin/contactus', 'ContactController');
        Route::resource('admin', 'AdminController');
        Route::get('admin/products/sold',['as'=>'sold', 'uses'=>'AdminProductsController@sold']);
        Route::resource('admin/faqs', 'AdminFaqController');

    });
```

**My Controller:**

```
 <?php

        namespace App\Http\Controllers;

        use Illuminate\Http\Request;

        class AdminFaqController extends Controller
        {
            /**
             * Display a listing of the resource.
             *
             * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
             */
            public function index()
            {
                //
                return view('admin.faqs.index');

            }
```

**My index.blade file:**

```
@extends('layouts.admin')
    @section('title', 'Know and your Brand')
    @section('content')
    <h2>Faqs</h2>
        @endsection
```

I have not been able to figure out what causes the problem, please help

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind getting blank pages is because Route::resource will create some route with wildcards. We can explain this using by giving an example `/admin/{admin}` which will map to show method on the controller. So when you make a get request to `/admin/faqs` it will be mapped to this show method instead of your `/admin/faqs`.

The reason for not getting any errors is your show method does not have any code yet. Hence, a blank response.

Try using,

```
Route::resource('/admin/homepage/faqs', 'AdminFaqController');
```

Comment: '''Route::resource('/admin/homepage/faqs', 'AdminFaqController');''' This worked for me. But I don't understand why the other routes just works fine without adding homepage

Comment: Its simply Route::resource will create multiple routes which overide other routes.

Answer (score 0):

In your command pro. simply type `php artisan route:list` you can see all of your routs URL paths.

In your case I think you should use `/` before `admin` like-

```php
Route::resource('/admin/faqs', 'AdminController');
```

As @Harshith said..

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to use html submit bouton to submit and blank
use this:

`<button type="submit" formtarget="_blank">Submit to a new window</button>`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).